# Make exclude target?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu

I am building coreutils for Windows.

You can get `su.exe` to build, but it is a hack.

My first idea was to skip it by putting

```
make basename.exe cat.exe cp.exe
```

and so on, but it seems like you should be able to do something like

```
make -su.exe
```

so that it skips that target.

Comment: Well there's always sed and make -f... :) You know what, I never thought about it. Maybe you could simply touch (create a blank) exe. If it sees it's already there, maybe it won't build it. If it still insists, maybe try the -o option to tell it not to remake. Will have to experiment...

Comment: If all else fails, why don't you just remove the target from the file ?

Comment: that's what I meant by `sed` and `make -f` (the two-second solution). There are also the -W file, --what-if=file, --new-file=file, --assume-new=file options to `make` that I never tried. (combined with the -n option of course) More candidates for experimentation obtained from the manual. 8D

Comment: The `-W file` option worked. It skipped building the file. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try `-W` option: `make -W su.exe`.

Comment: That's weird. It works over here. Let's see that makefile. Maybe it's doing something strange. Oh yeah, and I'm using GNU Make 3.82

Comment: Come to think of it, the Windows version of make probably has different command line options because Windows DOS is case-insensitive and -W would be confused with -w (print directory). You'll have to read your manual. Sorry. :(